# Same case class different validation

Tags: mongodb, scala, akka-http, case-class, spray-json

What I'm trying to do in Scala 2.11 and akka is have one case class but two different validations based on which route is being hit.

For example, let's consider the case class below

```
case class User(_id: String, name: String, age: Int, address: String)
```

Now while the `/create` route is hit, I don't need `_id` but I need all the other fields.

But while `/update` route is hit, I need the `_id` and the fields that are to be updated (which could be one or all three)

Only declaring `Option` doesn't serve the purpose because then my `/create` route goes for a toss.

Even extending case classes doesn't really work seamlessly (there's too much code duplicity).

I would love if something like this was possible

```
case class User(_id: String, name: String, age: Int, address: String)

case class SaveUser() extends User {
    require(name.nonEmpty)
    require(age.nonEmpty)
    require(address.nonEmpty)
}

case class UpdateUser() extends User {
    require(_id.nonEmpty)
}
```

Is there an elegant solution to this? Or do I have to create two identical case classes?

Comment: Use `scala-cats` `validation` applicative style

Comment: why can't you use option[_id] for the same case class? and you will get id from the update route and will not get _id in the create route? what's wrong with this design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to encode different case classes for different requirements, but if you insist you must share code between these two cases a possible solution would be to parameterize the case class

```
case class User[Id[_], Param[_]](_id: Id[String], name: Param[String], age: Param[Int], address: Param[String])
```

Then you define an alias for the Identity type constructor and your two uses of the case class

```
type Identity[T] = T
type SaveUser = User[Option, Identity]
type UpdateUser = User[Identity, Option]
```

Comment: Or composition rather than altering the `User` definitions due to a persistence concern (not interesting for read purpose by the end user); e.g. `case class Persistent[T](id: ..., value: T)` usable as `Persistent(anId, anUserOrElse)` (as `Persistent[User]`), with generic codecs for `Persistent` using appropriate `T` codecs (for nested or flattened encoding).

Comment: I took that the use case is that the attributes of User are individually optional in the case of an update.

Comment: @emilianogc Tried that. It was working as expected, even spray-json picked it up and could work. But I was planning to generate bson codecs for this automatically using mongo db codecs. But that couldn't be done since mongo for scala doesn't support such high inference. Had to revert to a kind of ugly solution.

But I'll accept this. Since this does exactly what I asked.